# Is disabling GPU reasonable for saving power during non-intensive usage?

Tags: graphics-card, power, hardware-rec

Consider having a upper mid-level gaming desktop PC that is (also) being used for casual work like text-editing, browsing, audio playback.

Could disabling the GPU (via "Disable device" in Window's Device Manager) cause a net decrease of power consumption?
Or would I need to remove the external GPU entirely, and plug my display cables into the mother board to actually have an (positive or negative) effect?
How would video playback affect the energy balance? Can an external GPU render video more *efficiently* (not performant) than the CPU's built-in graphics unit?

Comment: Your GPU should already clock itself back if it's not needed. Mine right now is ticking over at about ¼ of its clock speed, fans inaudible, desktop & 'static' apps running at a magnificent 2 fps. Memory is reasonably full, but that's not an issue at all, that's normal. https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6mUP.png

Comment: @Tetsujin yes, I am aware, that the GPU controls itself depending on workload. However, I still wonder if the base consumption that's caused by simply having the GPU running is possibly higher, than the additional power usage that was caused by the CPU doing the little graphics work.

Comment: If you disable the GPU you wouldn’t have a display. “Could disabling the GPU (via "Disable device" in Window's Device Manager) cause a net decrease of power consumption?” - No

Comment: @Ramhound sorry but this is not true. You can indeed disable the GPU and still have a screen. You'll just notice that the UI is not running so smooth anymore.

Comment: To disable the GPU and still have a screen, you need a second GPU. Possibly you have a weaker GPU built into the motherboard. Windows will switch to it automatically for undemanding tasks, disabling the stronger GPU. You don't need to do anything.

Comment: @harrymc Clearly the CPU's built-in GPU jumps in, when I disable the dedicated GPU. But that's not my question. I rather wonder, if using that CPU's built-in GPU is more power saving in comparison to simply using the main GPU.

Comment: There is no CPU's built-in GPU. You need to use the right terms. Perhaps you mean the difference between a video codec that is CPU-bound vs one that uses the GPU? I find your question to be unclear.

Comment: @harrymc Intel Core processors generally have a graphics unit built-in. Some AMD Ryzen CPUs do as well. These are what I refer to as "built-in GPU".

Comment: (See for example https://www.amd.com/en/processors/ryzen-with-graphics or https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/visual-technology/graphics-overview.html)

Comment: @Reizo Disabling the a device in Device Manager disables the driver, not the hardware. You aren't switching to the GPU integrated into the CPU when you disabled the discreet GPU's driver.

Comment: @Amorphous Ah thanks, good do know! Can you possibly tell what implications that has on power consumption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When not running an intensive workload on the GPU, the GPU uses only a tiny small fraction of its maximum designed power. Physically removing the GPU from the system will eliminate this power use.

Disabling a desktop GPU in the Device Manager only disables the driver. This may increase your overall power utilization:

1. Although most power control of the GPU is handled by firmware, disabling the driver may disable some power saving features managed by the driver
2. Disabling the GPU will increase CPU workload

   - Basic OS rendering will fall back to software mode, which will degrade your visual experience, and may be more less power efficient than the GPU
   - Video playback will be run in software mode on the CPU which may be less power efficient than the dedicated hardware within modern GPUs